# Build problems with clang

Tags: c++, clang, llvm

This is my first attempt at `clang`. I have successfully built `clang` with `llvm` and able to build simple C codes with

```
clang -Os -S -emit-llvm ../src/TestLLVM.c -O
```

Now when I am trying to build example LLVM code,

```
#include "clang/AST/ASTConsumer.h"
#include "clang/AST/RecursiveASTVisitor.h"
#include "clang/Frontend/CompilerInstance.h"
#include "clang/Frontend/FrontendAction.h"
#include "clang/Tooling/Tooling.h"

using namespace clang;

class FindNamedClassVisitor
  : public RecursiveASTVisitor<FindNamedClassVisitor> {
public:
  explicit FindNamedClassVisitor(ASTContext *Context)
    : Context(Context) {}

  bool VisitCXXRecordDecl(CXXRecordDecl *Declaration) {
    if (Declaration->getQualifiedNameAsString() == "n::m::C") {
      FullSourceLoc FullLocation = Context->getFullLoc(Declaration->getLocStart());
      if (FullLocation.isValid())
        llvm::outs() << "Found declaration at "
                     << FullLocation.getSpellingLineNumber() << ":"
                     << FullLocation.getSpellingColumnNumber() << "\n";
    }
    return true;
  }

private:
  ASTContext *Context;
};

class FindNamedClassConsumer : public clang::ASTConsumer {
public:
  explicit FindNamedClassConsumer(ASTContext *Context)
    : Visitor(Context) {}

  virtual void HandleTranslationUnit(clang::ASTContext &Context) {
    Visitor.TraverseDecl(Context.getTranslationUnitDecl());
  }
private:
  FindNamedClassVisitor Visitor;
};

class FindNamedClassAction : public clang::ASTFrontendAction {
public:
  virtual std::unique_ptr<clang::ASTConsumer> CreateASTConsumer(
    clang::CompilerInstance &Compiler, llvm::StringRef InFile) {
    return std::unique_ptr<clang::ASTConsumer>(
        new FindNamedClassConsumer(&Compiler.getASTContext()));

  }
};

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  if (argc > 1) {
    clang::tooling::runToolOnCode(new FindNamedClassAction, argv[1]);
  }
}
```

I am getting almost 3000 error messages upon building this :

```
/usr/local/include/clang/AST/Decl.h:2685:5:   instantiated from here
/usr/local/include/llvm/ADT/PointerUnion.h:132:75: error:        ‘getFromVoidPointer’ is not a member of ‘llvm::PointerLikeTypeTraits<clang::LazyGenerationalUpdatePtr<const    clang::Decl*, clang::Decl*, &clang::ExternalASTSource::CompleteRedeclChain> >’
In file included from /usr/local/include/clang/Basic/LLVM.h:22:0,
             from /usr/local/include/clang/AST/AttrIterator.h:17,
             from /usr/local/include/clang/AST/Attr.h:17,
             from /usr/local/include/clang/AST/RecursiveASTVisitor.h:17,
             from ../src/TestClang2.cpp:2:
/usr/local/include/llvm/Support/Casting.h: In static member function ‘static bool llvm::isa_impl<To, From, Enabler>::doit(const From&) [with To = clang::Type, From = clang::Type, Enabler = void]’:
/usr/local/include/llvm/Support/Casting.h:103:41:   instantiated from ‘static bool llvm::isa_impl_cl<To, const From* const>::doit(const From*) [with To = clang::Type, From = clang::Type]’
/usr/local/include/llvm/Support/Casting.h:122:44:   instantiated from ‘static bool llvm::isa_impl_wrap<To, FromTy, FromTy>::doit(const FromTy&) [with To = clang::Type, FromTy = const clang::Type* const]’
/usr/local/include/llvm/Support/Casting.h:134:78:   instantiated from ‘bool llvm::isa(const Y&) [with X = clang::Type, Y = const clang::Type*]’
/usr/local/include/llvm/Support/Casting.h:237:3:   instantiated from ‘typename llvm::cast_retty<X, Y*>::ret_type llvm::cast(Y*) [with X = clang::Type, Y = const clang::Type, typename llvm::cast_retty<X, Y*>::ret_type = const clang::Type*]’
/usr/local/include/clang/AST/TypeLoc.h:347:46:   instantiated from ‘const TypeClass* clang::ConcreteTypeLoc<Base, Derived, TypeClass, LocalData>::getTypePtr() const [with Base = clang::UnqualTypeLoc, Derived = clang::TypeSpecTypeLoc, TypeClass = clang::Type, LocalData = clang::TypeSpecLocInfo]’
/usr/local/include/clang/AST/TypeLoc.h:441:46:   instantiated from ‘const TypeClass* clang::InheritingConcreteTypeLoc<Base, Derived, TypeClass>::getTypePtr() const [with Base = clang::TypeSpecTypeLoc, Derived = clang::TypedefTypeLoc, TypeClass = clang::TypedefType]’
/usr/local/include/clang/AST/TypeLoc.h:592:12:   instantiated from here
/usr/local/include/llvm/Support/Casting.h:56:28: error: ‘classof’ is not a member of ‘clang::Type’
```

The output of `which clang` is

```
~/development/llvm/build/Release+Asserts/bin/clang
```

**Edit 1** : I have made a /etc/ld.so.conf.d/llvm.conf file and added
`~/development/llvm/build/Release+Asserts/lib` to it, and still output of

`sudo ldconfig -p | grep LLVM` is

```
libLLVM-3.4.so.1 (libc6) => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libLLVM-3.4.so.1
libLLVM-3.4.so (libc6) => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libLLVM-3.4.so
libLLVM-3.2.so.1 (libc6) => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libLLVM-3.2.so.1
```

But I guess it should have been

```
~/development/llvm/build/Release+Asserts/lib
```

?

**Edit 2** My CMakeLists.txt has lines

```
message(STATUS "Using LLVMConfig.cmake in: ${LLVM_DIR}")
message(STATUS "Using LLVMConfig.cmake in: ${LLVM_INCLUDE_DIRS}")
```

which outputs as :

```
-- Using LLVMConfig.cmake in: /usr/local/share/llvm/cmake
-- Using LLVMConfig.cmake in: /usr/local/include
```

Where are these paths being set?

Comment: you get compile errors, so the linking issue is not yet relevant. i guess clang includes the wrong headers, located at `/usr/local/include` instead of your development version. try specifying the location of the headers using `-I` or, even better, install your development version of clang systemwide.

Comment: I have already done `make install` after building the llvm source code. Isn't that how you install the headers as well?

Comment: So `/usr/local/include/clang/` contains the headers from your development clang version?

Comment: yes. I have not installed clang before this

Comment: Why is `which clang` not pointing to `/usr/local/bin/clang`?

Comment: interesting! but the include folder my development clang version is almost empty. All the includes are still in `llvm-src/include`. How can I point it to this folder?

Comment: Apparently there was still clang-3.4 installed. I have removed all those packages. But now `sudo ldconfig -p | grep LLVM` is just empty. Why isn't llvm.conf being updated even after `sudo ldconfig` ?

Comment: You can't just go ahead and use individual build commands to build a RecursiveAstVisitor pass. You need  a makefile and build it with the clang, read this 
http://clang.llvm.org/docs/RAVFrontendAction.html

Comment: I followed the same tutorial. Do I need to setup something for clang to work with cmake? Because adding `-DCMAKE_C_COMPILER=clang -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=clang++` doesn't seem to make any difference.

Comment: I was able to build an example by placing the code in `llvm-src/tools/clang/examples/` But I still haven't understood how these makefiles work. Why am I unable to build outside the source directory?